# Powershell String Replace Strange behaviour with umlauts

Tags: powershell, str-replace

I have a strange behaviour of the Powershell String -Replace Function.

My Code looks like this:

```
$lastname = $lastname -replace "ü","ue" 
$lastname
Enable-Mailbox -Identity <DistiguishedName> -Alias ($firstname + "." + $lastname)
$lastname
$lastname.Length
```

The -Alias Parameter of `Enable-Mailbox` gives me the error that I have a non-working char in my `$lastname`.

But the Output Actually looks like this:
[image: Output With Error-Code]

I think it cant be the Enable-Mailbox Statement because its working with non Umlaut-Names.
Why should the variable have the right value and length and then when I pass it to a command be another?

Greetings

Comment: That doesn't look to have anything to do with your alias. That looks to be an internal error with the data it fetched and is trying to work with (which has an umlaut in it presumably).

Comment: Ok, I will try searching after that. So you mean the Enable-Mailbox Function does get some other data from somewhere else?

Comment: You where right. `Enable-Mailbox` Function did also search after an Smtp-Address in AD and was finding an entry there. And then the Alias I have given wasn't even touched. Thanks for your input!